# Typo3: Only JPGs too dark

Tags: imagemagick, typo3, jpeg

I have the problem JPGs are too dark when they are resized. PNGs are fine.

I know from other installations, that the colorspace of imagemagick has to be sRGB and I changed that:

```
-set colorspace sRGB +profile ‚*‘
```

But JPGs are still too dark and I can't find what other config could cause that.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

As the **Install Tool** says:

```
[GFX][colorspace]

String: Specifiy the colorspace to use.
Some ImageMagick versions (like 6.7.0 and above) use the sRGB colorspace,
so all images are darker then the original.
```

Means that if you use the `sRGB` default color profile, you will get **darker** images.

Solution? Just use the `RGB` color profile.

I had this same issue with multiple installations of Typo3 6.2.x and Typo3 7.6.x.

-EDIT-

It appears that recently the issue can be solved by switching back to `sRGB`. Although what I suggest is trying to switch from one to another, until you get it fixed.

Unfortunately this is up to Image Magick team, when they will make sure that the related piece of code will never change, we will finally have a definitive answer. Thanks to [@Rajiv007](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1957780/rajiv007) for pointing me to this.

Comment: My case opposite happened. Changed RGB to sRGB and my images got original color.

Comment: I think this answer really depends on what ImageMagick is doing behind the scenes. I got some issue recently on another web application which is currently using RGB and sRGB fixed that issue.

When the ImageMagick team will finally make sure that this code will never change, then we will have a final answer to this question :)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the colorspace in the install tool, there is a whole graphics  part (GFX) in the config section you might want to check. If possible, use GraphicsMagick instead of ImageMagick. Check if "truecolor" is set to true. Change the JPG-Quality to 100 for testing.

Comment: And make sure to clean ``typo3temp\`` while testing.

Comment: Truecolor in this case has nothing to do with `JPG`, it's only for `PNG` files. Quality also makes no difference on the color.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with different imagemagick versions.

See [this blog post](http://blog.dev001.net/post/32682776195/typo3-workaround-for-too-dark-images-since) and [the corresponding typo3 bug](https://forge.typo3.org/issues/36597). You can set the color space in the install tool now.